# Rails link_to puts in url in adress bar but doesnt go to the new page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I'm new to rails and my link_to isn't working correctly. It shows the new page in the address bar but doesn't load the page unless I hit enter to force the load. Thank you for all the help!

routes.rb

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
    root 'static_pages#home'
    get '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'
 end
```

static_pages_controller.rb

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
   def home
   end

   def about
   end
end
```

home.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "About", about_path%>
```

Comment: this is some problem due to `turbolinks`. Turbolinks captures all the click events on `links`, changes history and loads the page. Make sure you do not see any errors in browser console when you click the link.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help im getting the error Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '<' is not a valid attribute name.

Comment: This error is preventing the `Turbolinks` to fetch the page. Because, any error in JS runtime exits the whole program and code beneath it do not get executed. #happycoding

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!